# OpenGL- glFrustum, glLoadIdentity and glLookAt Confusion

Tags: opengl, glut, glfw, freeglut

I am trying to achieve a perspective view for a rectangular plane in the X-Z axis like below.

[image]

The code below almost achieves that.

[image]

What am i doing wrong? I find the documentation to be lacking/confusing.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

const int RED_COLOR[3] = {255, 0, 0};

// color to draw in
void setDrawColor(const int decimalCodeRGB[3]) {

    float denominator = 255.0;
    //convert to float
    float r = decimalCodeRGB[0] / denominator;
    float g = decimalCodeRGB[1] / denominator;
    float b = decimalCodeRGB[2] / denominator;

    glColor3f(r, g, b); // set draw color
}

void drawPlane() {
    GLfloat A[3] = { -1, 0,  1 };
    GLfloat B[3] = { 1,  0,  1 };
    GLfloat C[3] = { 1,  0, -1 };
    GLfloat D[3] = { -1, 0, -1 };

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3fv(A);
        glVertex3fv(B);
        glVertex3fv(C);
        glVertex3fv(D);
    glEnd();
}


GLfloat CamX = 0, CamY = 2, CamZ = 1;
// Display Call Back
void draw() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear all drawings in buffer
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(CamX, CamY, CamZ, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    drawPlane();
    glutSwapBuffers();// Render Now i.e convert Buffer to Picture
    return;
}

// Initialization
void initialize()
{
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); // Set Background Color
    setDrawColor(RED_COLOR);              //  sets the drawing color to red 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);             // enable viewing the 3d
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);         // change to perspective projection
    glLoadIdentity();                       // what does this do?
    glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 2, 10);         // what does this do?
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);             // what does this do?

}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize GLUT
    int x = 512, y = 512;  // x and y value
    glutInitWindowPosition(
        (int)(glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) - x) / 2,
        (int)(glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) - y) / 2);              // Position the window's center
    glutInitWindowSize(x, y);                                     // Set the window's initial width & height
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);     // initialise the buffers needed. double buff, one for RGB color the other for x,y, z
    glutCreateWindow("3D Bowling Game");                          // Create a window with the given title
    initialize();                                   // Custom initialisation    
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);                          // Register display callback handler for window re-paint    
    glutMainLoop();                                 // Enter the event-processing loop

    return 0;
}
// End
```

How do I change the camera to 45 degrees to Z axis?
Am i calling the functions in the right Order?

Comment: What exactly do you think is wrong? It looks fine to me.

Comment: For 45° you have to set `CamY = 2`, `CamZ = 2`.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the rectangle will come from the bottom of the screen to the middle